# Scala scopt error with Seq[String]

Tags: scala, implicit, scopt

I'm trying to create a [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) option for `Seq[String]`:

```
import scopt._
import scopt.Read._
opt[Seq[String]]("foobar")
                ^ error
```

but the compiler complains that it `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scopt.Read[Seq[String]]`.

I'm using Scala 2.11.2 and scopt 3.3.0.

Am I missing an `import` or something else?

Comment: Could you provide a full example?

Comment: Btw: When using sbt, the project will be automatically updated to Scala 2.11.4 for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be resolved in scopt "3.6.0"

here's what my build.sbt looks like:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0" ,
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.6.0")
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scopt/scopt/blob/scopt3/src/main/scala/scopt/options.scala), it looks like you just need to `import scopt.Read`. This will import the Read companion object which contains an implicit to handle this for you:

```
// reads("1,2,3,4,5") == Seq(1,2,3,4,5)
implicit def seqRead[A: Read]: Read[Seq[A]] = reads { (s: String) =>
  s.split(sep).map(implicitly[Read[A]].reads)
}
```

Note: I have not run this through a REPL to verify, but it should work.